# Accessing nth element from tuples in list, but the length of the tuple is different

Tags: python, list, tuples

For example I have a list of tuple like this, the last element of the first tuple is empty:

```
data=[('1',),('2','3'),('6','5'),('3','4')]
```

I want to get the last element of each tuple, I use something like this, for i, j in data, if j is not empty then make j as list:

```
    lastelemtent=list(set([j for i,j in data if j]))[0]
```

I get the error: `not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`
I want to get result like: `lastelemtent=['3','5','4']`.

Comment: `[t[1] for t in data if len(t) == 2]`? As the error tells you, it simply can't unpack `(1,)` to `i, j`.

Comment: "the last element of the first tuple is empty:" nope, `('1',)` is just a tuple with just a single element

Comment: I change it to [t[-1] for t in data if len(t) > 1], it works, thanks @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 2):

You can use the syntax `something[-1]` to select the last element of a list of tuples.

To get the last element of each tuple from your data, you have to run

```
lastelement = [e[-1] for e in data]
```

Comment: But that's not the output the OP wants

Comment: If you check the original question, the author did not posted the desired output only a line as "I want to get the last element of each tuple". I wrote my answer when it was posted.

Comment: It did already say *"if j is not empty"*, though, and the filter in the list comprehension matched that intention.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I missed that part even for the nth read.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want the second element of each tuple except if the tuple is shorter.

```
[x[1] for x in data if len(x) > 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your premise is wrong. The "last element" in `('1',)` is not empty, but that's just a tuple with only a single element, that's why you get "not enough values to unpack". This also means that `'1'` is both the first *and* last element of that tuple, so using the index `[-1]` will work (not produce an error) but might not do what you expect or want.

If you want an "empty" last element, maybe you can use `('1', '')` or `('1', None)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to unpack a tuple of size 1 `(1,)` to a tuple of size 2: `i, j`. You can use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

```
lastelemtent = [j for *i, j in data if i]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data=[('1',7),('2','3'),('6','5'),('3','4')]
lastelement = [i[-1] for i in data]
```

`lastelement` will contain this -->[7,3,5,4]